# Animating circle drawing in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I am trying to animate circle drawing using `drawCircle` on `Canvas` as follows:

```
 drawCircle(
     color = Color.Black,
     radius = 200f * animatableCircle.value,
     center = Offset(size.width / 4, size.height / 4),
     style = Stroke(2f)
)
```

[image]
It doesn't look like circle is being drawn, instead the circle starts to scale from the centre. Is it possible to achieve circle drawing effect as in along the radius similar to `CircularProgressIndicator` as shown?
[image]

Comment: Sure it is possible, with `drawArc` https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ProgressIndicator.kt;l=332?q=progressindicator%20compose

Comment: Thank you so much! Added as answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to complete the code posted by [@Varsha Kulkarni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67081027/2016562): (+1)

```
    val radius = 200f
    val animateFloat = remember { Animatable(0f) }
    LaunchedEffect(animateFloat) {
        animateFloat.animateTo(
            targetValue = 1f,
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 3000, easing = LinearEasing))
    }

   Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
       drawArc(
           color = Color.Black,
           startAngle = 0f,
           sweepAngle = 360f * animateFloat.value,
           useCenter = false,
           topLeft = Offset(size.width / 4, size.height / 4),
           size = Size(radius * 2 ,
               radius * 2),
           style = Stroke(2.0f))
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This sure is the complete answer:)

Answer (score 3):

Using `drawArc` as follows,

```
 drawArc(
     color = Color.Black,
     startAngle = 0f,
     sweepAngle = 360f * animatableCircle.value,
     useCenter = false,
     topLeft = Offset(size.width / 4, size.height / 4),
     size = Size(CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2 ,
                 CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2),
     style = Stroke(2.0f))
```